# How do I read from a table and update another table usign stored procedures in Oracle DB?

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to read records from 'table1' based on created_date. If created_date in table1 is less than current_date, I need to update a Boolean column in table2.

eg:

```
    Table 1

    ID  Col1   Col2   Created_Date
    1   test   test   25-Apr-2016
    2   test   test   23-Apr-2016

    Table 2

    ID Col11 Col12 Col_Boolean
    2  test  test  false
```

I need to update column Col_Boolean in table 2 where ID is ID from table 1 for created_date less than current date.

Comment: What exactly have you tried / where's the code you're having a problem with?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt - I haven't tried anything :-) I'm new to queries and stored procedures

Comment: Does a row already exist for ID=2 in table 2 and you just need to update the Boolean? And if so how come there is no row for ID=1 also, with the Boolean set to True? The solution for your case may be a MERGE rather than UPDATE or INSERT, but that is more advanced than where you seem to be in your study of SQL. By the way, you are aware that there is no Boolean data type in Oracle database, right? You have to use char or varchar2 data type to emulate Boolean, probably best for Col_Boolean to be of type char(1) with a check constraint to only be allowed to be either T or F.

Answer (score 1):

```
update table_2 set col_boolean 'false'
  where id in (select id from table_1 where created_date < sysdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update table2 set col_boolean = 'false'
where exists (select null 
            from table1
            where table1.id = table2.id
            and table1.created_date < sysdate);
```